# Android : How can I update a variable after using in for loop

Tags: java

I have done this code,

```
if (k == 21 && click1 == true)
{   
    for (k = 21; k < 39; k++) {
        Spinner sp = (Spinner) gridLayout.getChildAt(k);
        String value = (String) sp.getSelectedItem();
        Log.d("Spinner value als string", value);
        if (!value.isEmpty()) {
            value1 = Integer.parseInt(value);
            ("Spinner value als invert", ""+ value1);
            sum = sum + value1;
            Log.d("Totall Value", "" + sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Here the value k has been updated as 39 after iteration and i want use this value to a variable as 39 so that next this loop doesn't start again and I can use this to another loop or iteration. 
Help needed !!

Comment: But you know it's 39 since it's written in the loop.. Why don't you use... simply 39?

Comment: I didn't get it too... Also, if you're gonna use the k right after that, it's value will indeed be 39, so you can use it again.

Comment: i need to update value k after iteration cause after iteration i can compute total result through value from spinner and i can move on to next column where updated value will be use to compute another column for result calculation.

Answer (score 1):

if I understood it correctly, what left for you is to declare this variable as a class-field.

```
public class YourClass {

    public int k = 0;

    public void yourMethod(){
        if (k == 21 && click1 == true)
        {   
            for (k = 21; k < 39; k++) {
                Spinner sp = (Spinner) gridLayout.getChildAt(k);
                String value = (String) sp.getSelectedItem();
                Log.d("Spinner value als string", value);
                if (!value.isEmpty()) {
                    value1 = Integer.parseInt(value);
                    ("Spinner value als invert", ""+ value1);
                    sum = sum + value1;
                    Log.d("Totall Value", "" + sum);
                }
             }
        }

    }
}
```